# how to implement Row per page using Drop Down box above Webgrid and update webgrid every selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, webgrid

i have create one Drop Downbox above Webgrid and if user select any value from Drop down box my webgrid change the row per page so...but it not work proper and my webgrid is not updated 
so please give me hint to implement it..
this is my Code..here 
VIEW....CODE

```
<div id="contentwrapper" class="contentwrapper">

                  <form id="opation" action="">
                  <div class="tableoptions">                                            
                   <button class="submit radius2" id="Act" onclick="submitForm(this.id);">Active</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="submit radius2" id="Dec" onclick="submitForm(this.id);">DeActive</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="submit radius2" id="Del" onclick="submitForm(this.id);">Delete</button>&nbsp;&nbsp; @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions{ InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "myGrid" })) { <label>Search User: </label><input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" value=""/> <button class="submit radius2" id="Search" value="Search">Search</button>}                       
                  </div> 
                 </form>
                 Record Per Page:&nbsp;<form id="test" action=""><select name="DD" class="tbl_top_link" name="Pagelimit" id="Pagelimit" onchange="Count(this.value);"><option value="">- Select -</option><option id="1" value="1">1</option><option id="5" value="5">5</option><option id="10" value="10">10</option><option id="20" value="20">20</option><option id="30" value="30">30</option></select></form>
```

```
                          @{      

                               var temp = converttoInt16(ViewData["Pagesize"]);
                              var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
                                                       defaultSort: "Name", rowsPerPage: temp,
                                                          selectionFieldName: "SelectedRow", canPage: true);

                                                 //grid.Pager(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                                                 //     firstText: "First", lastText: "Last",
                                                 //     previousText: "Previous",
                                                 //     nextText: "Next",  
                                                 //     numericLinksCount: 15);


                          <div id="mygrid">
                                             @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "gridTable",
                                                     headerStyle: "gridHead",
                                                     footerStyle: "gridFooter",
                                                     rowStyle: "gridRow",
                                                     alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",
                                                columns: grid.Columns(
                                                         grid.Column(header: "", format: @<text><input type="checkbox" name="chkactive[]" id="chkactive[]" value="@item.User_id"/></text>),
                                                grid.Column("User_Id"),
                                                grid.Column("Name"),
                                                grid.Column("Username"),
                                                grid.Column("Fb_Id"),
                                                grid.Column("User_image", format: @<text><img src="@Url.Content(@item.Image_path)" height="30px" width="50px" alt="noimage"/></text>),
                                                grid.Column("Email"),
                                                grid.Column("Gender"),
                              grid.Column(header: "Status", format: @<text>@if (@item.Is_active == true)
                                                                           { <a href="@Url.Action("UserStatus", "Admin", new { id = @item.User_id })"><img src="../../images/Active.png"/></a> }
                                                                           else
                                                                           { <a href="@Url.Action("UserStatus", "Admin", new { id = @item.User_id })"><img src="../../images/Deactive.png"/></a> }</text>),
                               grid.Column(header: "Edit",
                                          format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("EditeUser", "Admin", new { id = @item.User_id })"><img src="../../images/icons/editor.png" /></a></text>),
                               grid.Column(header: "Delete",
                                         format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "Admin", new { id = @item.User_id })"><img src="../../images/icons/trash.png"/></a></text>)))

                                    </div>   
                              } 

                            </tbody>
                        </table> 
                      </form>                                                                     
                    </div>
```

in this view i have one DRop down box and Onchange event are call the my java sript to identified which value is selected and after post to My Action result method to perform to my logic and and return to view but my view is not change or webgrid is not updated..
so pleas help me ..or show me way to how i can perform this functionality using dropdown on webgrid

this is my JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function Count(value) 
{
    alert(value);

     $.post('@Url.Action("Pagesize","Admin")',
                    {
                        rowsPerPage: value                          
                    });             
}
```

This is my Action Result method:----

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Pagesize(int rowsPerPage)
    {

        //if (rowsPerPage == 0)
        //{
        //   ViewBag.Pagesize = 3;                
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    ViewBag.Pagesize = Convert.ToInt32(rowsPerPage);               
        //}

         ViewData["pagesize"] = rowsPerPage;

         //return View(db.User_Masters.ToList());  

        // return RedirectToAction("Userlist");    

         var u_master = db.User_Masters.ToList();


         return PartialView("OneRow",u_master);

    }
```

Comment: I do not see any DropDownList in your code.

Comment: Show above Code view in Last Line ..see carefully .

Answer (score 0):

Try this following method, it works fine, please correct with your table name where ever specified.. Good Luck!

in view :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
             {
              <p>Some name to search: @Html.DropDownList("searchString", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CurrentFilter, "-Select-", new {style = "width:200px;", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
              </p>
             }
```

in controller:

```
public ViewResult Viewname(string currentFilter, string searchString)
        {
            ViewBag.searchString = new SelectList(db.tablename, "Some name to search", "Some name to search");
            if (Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }
            var Search = from objCampaign in db.tablename
                               join objClient in db.othertablenameon objCampaign.field equals objClient.field
                               select objCampaign;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                Search = Search.Where(objsearch => objsearch.tablename.searchname.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }
            if (Search.Count() == 0)
            {
                TempData["infosearch"] = "No Client Found";
            }
            return View(Search.ToList());
        }
```

thank you
GorPedoC